# What kind of functions has those conditions?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I am trying to think on a function that has sequence of  singularity points at $z_0=\pm1$ and also a sequence of simple poles (whatever point I would like)

I thought on the function $$f(z)= \frac{1}{sin(\frac{1}{z-1})sin(\frac{1}{z+1})}$$

so I have $z_k= \frac{1}{2\pi k} \pm1$

But I can't think on the part with the poles.

Comment: If you want your sequence of poles on a line, you could use a linear transform to map the line onto the x-as and then use the same trick as you have done for the singularities with the sines.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem

Comment: @Yadeses you mean multiply by $\frac{1}{z-k}$? for any $k$?